# Limiting the number of items in a gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I am implementing a gridview in Android and my requirement is that I want that only 9 items come on 1 page and if there are more than 9 items in a gridview than rest of them should come on the next page. Is it possible??

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The method that you override to get count in the Custom Image Adapter that extends Base Adapter. This method gives the number of items to be added.

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return imageList.size();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Divide your data set into blocks of nine, give the first set of nine to the adapter that you are using for the `GridView`. Have a `Button` for next page give the next data set block to the adapter and tell the adapter that the data set has changed.

Comment: I dont have the button provision here and all the data to the gridview is added dynamically one bye one ( say images are added one by one after click) and also they can be deleted.

Comment: Are you using `GridView` or `GridLayout`, since `GridView` uses an adapter like `ListView`, it might actually be easier to use a `GridLayout` and then use a swipe gesture to move to the next set of nine elements.

Comment: Draksia, actually i am using Android Gridview